# ASP.NET MVC 5 error al consumir api con HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, api, asp

estoy consumiendo una api por medio del servicio HttpClient el cual funciona bien, pero al momento de hacer otra solicitud me lanza una excepción no controlada. Con esto ultimo me refiero a que al hacer el primer request me devuelve la respuesta bien, pero al darle f5 y hacer otro request me lanza esto...

> Esta instancia ya inició una o varias solicitudes. Solo se pueden modificar las propiedades antes de enviar la primera solicitud.
>
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: Esta instancia ya inició una o varias solicitudes. Solo se pueden modificar las propiedades antes de enviar la primera solicitud.
>
> Línea 16:         public async Task IndexAsync()
>   Línea 17:         {
>   Línea 18:             client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.36.159:5000/");
>   Línea 19:             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
>   Línea 20:             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(

Como lo puedo solucionar?. Este es mi código.

Controller:

```
// GET: Testing
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:5000/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("authorization");
        var persona = await GetProductAsync("api");
        return View(persona);
    }
```

Mi metodo estatico del servicio HttpClient

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Mi metodo que me devuelve el response

```
static async Task<object> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
        object Obj = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Persona>();
        }
        return Obj;
    }
```

Cabe destacar que todo este codigo lo tengo en unm archivo NombreController.cs seria ideal que igual me pudieran orientar de como separarlo para poder reutilizarlo en todas las consultas que debo hacer en la aplicacion. Gracias.

Comment: Creo que porque estaba haciendo dos peticiones, una que nunca se realiza y las otra que se realiza correctamente, esta nunca se acompleta `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:5000/");`, y solo te devuelve los datos de `GetProductAsync`, que es la que se esta realizando correctamente

Comment: Y si pruebas desde postman haciendo multiples solicitudes, te da el mismo problema? En caso contrario, entonces es la API que no permite varias solicitudes en cierto rango de tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Este error lo he tenido hace poco, (es mas, aun estoy resolviendo parte de la logica para este problema).

Lo que pude averiguar es que al usar el cliente, este no es liberado para la siguiente peticion que se quiere realizar. Supuestamente, usar el static es parte de la solucion.
¿Porque lo usas en el action que genera la vista?

Mira este enlace donde te indica bastante acerca de HttpClient 
https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Espero haberte guiado un poco y ojala alguien tenga una mejor respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tuve el mismo error, se que es viejo el articulo pero quizas le pueda servir a alguien mas la respuesta.

Lo resolvi agregando estas lineas:

```
_httpClient = new HttpClient();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ProxyAuthorization = null;
```

antes de llamar a un nuevo metodo. Lo que hace es limpiar el http client.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una instancia para el `HttpClient()` siempre y cuando las llamadas estén relacionadas, de lo contrario, puedes crear otra instancia.

##### Esto puede generar el error

```
public async Task Funcion(int id)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var llamadaUno = client.Funcion1QueOcupaHttpClient();
      var llamadaDos = client.Funcion2QueOcupaHttpClient();
   }
}
```

##### Solución 1

```
public async Task Funcion(int id)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var llamadaUno = client.Funcion1QueOcupaHttpClient();
          
      var client2 = new HttpClient(); // Genera una nueva instancia para usarla
      var llamadaDos = client2.Funcion2QueOcupaHttpClient();
   }
}
```

##### Otra Solución al ejemplo

```
public async Task Funcion(int id)
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   var llamadaDos = client.Funcion2QueOcupaHttpClient();
        
   var client2 = new HttpClient();
   var llamadaDos = client2.Funcion2QueOcupaHttpClient();
}
```